# Why does calling Min() on an empty list of references does not throw?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, value-type, reference-type

Consider the following:

```
var emptyValueList = new List<int>(); //any value type (long, float, any struct ...)
var minimum = emptyValueList.Min();
```

This will throw an `InvalidOperationException` (*Sequence contains no elements*).

Now let's try with a reference type:

```
var emptyReferenceList = new List<object>(); //any ref type will do such as object ...
var minimum = emptyReferenceList.Min();
```

This does not throw and returns `null`. It's as if the `default` operator was called for the second case but not for the first. It works as well for nullable types (e.g. `int?`, even though they're value types).

I was wondering why that was the case and if there was a specific reasoning behind this?

Comment: new List<int?>(); int? mean that it is nullable, thats the reason why it did not throw any error

Comment: The unsatisfactory answer is, of course, that that's what those functions are documented [to](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339189(v=vs.110).aspx) [do](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341201(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is a design decision that we will have to ask the authors of the BCL about.

There are various overloads of the [`Min` extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.min.aspx). For types that allow `null`, I believe `Min` skips all `null` values when searching for the minimum. This goes for both reference types and the [type `Nullable<>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) (in your example `Nullable<int>`) which is not a reference type, but which allows `null` (that the `Min` methods decide to disregard).

So with non-nullable structs, the authors of `Min` probably thought it would be "dangerous" to return `default(TSource)` since that could be a meaningfull (i.e. non-null) minimum in other cases (often the number `0`), and hence the output could be misunderstood.

With types that allow `null`, because the authors chose to skip `null` values yielded from the source, one can safely assume that `null` is returned only if the sequence contains nothing but `null` values (including the case of en empty source).

---

Note that under the standard `IComparer<>` for nullable types or reference types, the `null` value is less than any non-null value. For sorting algorithms (like the one used by `List<>.Sort`) the *order* must be total and transitive. We therefore get:

```
  Console.WriteLine(
    Comparer<int?>.Default.Compare(null, 7)
    ); // "-1"

  Console.WriteLine(
    Nullable.Compare((int?)null, 7)
    ); // "-1"


  Console.WriteLine(
    new List<int?> { 9, null, 7, 13, }
    .OrderBy(ni => ni).First()
    ); // ""


  // 'Min' is special in that it disregards 'null' values
  Console.WriteLine(
    new List<int?> { 9, null, 7, 13, }
    .Min()
    ); // "7"
```

And `Min` works the same way for true reference types, for example [`System.Version`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.aspx) (which is a `class` type):

```
  var li = new List<Version> { new Version("9.0"), null, new Version("7.0"), new Version("13.0"), };

  Console.WriteLine(li.OrderBy(ve => ve).First());
  Console.WriteLine(li.Min());
```

Comment: Interesting, didn't know that special behavior of `Min` (and `Max` I guess). Sounds like sumulating the respective sql aggregate functions.

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider using an extension:

```
using System.Linq;
public static class EnumerableExtensions {

    public static X MinOrDefault<T, X>(this IEnumerable<T> that, Func<T, X> minXp, X defaultValue) {
        if (that.Any())
            return that.Min(minXp);
        else
            return defaultValue;
    }
}

...

var emptyValueList = new List<int>();
var minimum = emptyValueList.MinOrDefault(e => e, 0);

var emptyEmployeeList = new List<Employee>();
var minimumSalary = emptyEmployeeList.MinOrDefault(e => e.Salary, 0);
```